# How to add statically created library in My application..?

Tags: iphone

I have created static library for testing.
I have used:
http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/15/how-to-create-universal-static-libraries-on-xcode-4/#identifier_0_432

Its created sucessfully as test.a now i want to add this library in my application.

can anybody help me out for this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `Xcode`.
2. Click on project file (the first item in `Project navigator`)
3. Select one of appropriate `target`
4. Open `Build Phases`
5. Select `Link Binary With Libraries`
6. Add your **library**

Answer (score 0):

check this link

http://www.amateurinmotion.com/articles/2009/02/08/creating-a-static-library-for-iphone.html

and go for **Link binary, Direct dependency** this will refer you static library to your xcode project .